# Show and hide div based on the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection, show-hide

I want to hide div for all which are not active. but when ever i reload all the tab contents come into one. Below is a screenshot of the the UI where am facing the problem.

[image]

Below are the code.

```js
$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
      
      e.preventDefault();
      
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      
      target = $(this).attr('href');
    
      $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
      
      $(target).fadeIn(600);
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form animated fadeInDown ">
          
          <ul class="tab-group">
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#roles">Roles</a></li>
            <li class="tab "><a href="#user">User</a></li>
      <li class="tab "><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="tab "><a href="#programs">Programs</a></li>
      <li class="tab "><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li class="tab "><a href="#phases">Phases</a></li>
      <li class="tab "><a href="#tasks">Tasks</a></li>
          </ul>
          
          <div class="tab-content">
                   
            <div id="roles" >   
              <h1> Roles coming soon</h1>
              
              </div>
      
      <div id="user">   
              <h1>Users added soon</h1>
    
            </div>
      
      <div id="portfolio">   
              <h1>Portfolio added soon</h1>
    
            </div>
      
      <div id="programs">   
              <h1>Programs added soon</h1>
    
            </div>
      
      <div id="projects">   
              <h1>Projects added soon</h1>
    
            </div>
      
      <div id="phases">   
              <h1>Phases added soon</h1>
    
            </div>
      
      <div id="tasks">   
              <h1>Tasks added soon</h1>
    
            </div>
      
      
            
          </div>
          
    </div>
```

I tried as much as possible but couldn't get this thing right. A help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the given CSS, other than that your code seems working for me.

```js
//See the first tab visible by default
$($('.tab-group > li.active').children('a').attr('href')).show();

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
  
  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

```css
.tab-content div{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form animated fadeInDown ">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#roles">Roles</a></li>
        <li class="tab "><a href="#user">User</a></li>
        <li class="tab "><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="tab "><a href="#programs">Programs</a></li>
        <li class="tab "><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="tab "><a href="#phases">Phases</a></li>
        <li class="tab "><a href="#tasks">Tasks</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="roles">   
          <h1> Roles coming soon</h1>

          </div>

        <div id="user">   
          <h1>Users added soon</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="portfolio">   
          <h1>Portfolio added soon</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="programs">   
          <h1>Programs added soon</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="projects">   
          <h1>Projects added soon</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="phases">   
          <h1>Phases added soon</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="tasks">   
          <h1>Tasks added soon</h1>

        </div>



      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i want to show the content of roles by default. how am i supposed to achieve that .

Comment: @Jeeva I've updated the code, check it. Applied style="display: block" to roles content.

Comment: sorry i had not seen that. any possibility of achieving this using the above jQuery itself?

Comment: @Jeeva See my answer, I've updated and roles are shown using jQuery.

Comment: @Jeeva : Is everything ok ?

Comment: thanks a lot i'll update you tomorrow. hope it works :) and other solution was also good. thank you